# Setting font in TeXstudio

Tags: fonts, xetex

OK, I am really new and I do not know how to change the default font to something more supportive of non-standard Latin characters.

So I have this for the preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper,onecolumn]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[width=6.50in, height=10.00in, left=0.50in, right=0.25in, top=0.25in, bottom=0.25in]{geometry}
```

and I know that the `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` is the font, however I do not know how to change the font as I do not know what my options are.

Can I use regular `.ttf` fonts that are already installed on my computer? I really want to use the Charis SIL font, however if I cannot, can you suggest a font that would be compatible with the letter "ȧ" as well as other linguistic IPA characters?

P.S. I've changed the compiler to XeLaTeX because I've read that it supports .ttf, but so far, I don't see that/know how to make it work...

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Don't load `inputenc` if you are using XeTeX. In any case, it doesn't affect the font but only tells TeX how your input is encoded. XeTeX uses utf-8 regardless. If you are using XeLaTeX, you can use fonts installed for your OS, yes. Use `fontspec` to select fonts. It has a good manual with plenty of examples.

Comment: @crf     \fontspec seems to give me an error as "undefined control sequence". EDIT: or use fontspec in place of inputenc?

Comment: It is a package. Yes, use `\usepackage{fontspec}` and don't use `inputenc` at all. See example below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a minimal example using Charis SIL truetype fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}


\begin{document}

Charis SIL.

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample]

Comment: @Manofzelego - Words of thanks are nice, but the tex.stackexchange way to express thanks is to "accept" the answer that works for you. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for details.

Comment: I get an error: Fatal package fontspec: complaining about fontspec oly being usde for Luatex or XeTeX, so not MiKTex, any workaround
(Using TeXStudio on win11)

Comment: @user189283 You have to compile with either LuaTeX or XeTeX. That error means you used either pdfTeX or (less likely) TeX. I don't know what you mean by `so not MiKTeX`. MiKTeX provides LuaTeX and XeTeX just as surely as TeX Live does. You don't need a workaround. You just need to use one of the two supported ways of compiling. This will work fine on Windows 11 and TeXStudio is just an editor. It might have a special option for setting the compiler, but it is irrelevant otherwise. At the command line, you'd write `lualatex <filename>` or `xelatex <filename>` where `<filename>` is the tex file.